# Allow only one section to be expand in section header using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, header, sections

Here is my code that I am using to expand and collapse the header section. Trying to allow only one section to be expanded. So when the user taps another section, it will first collapse the expanded one, and then expand the new one. Please share the info by which I get only one section to be expand at one time. As I use this code, it's not working as above. It opens more than one section, not closing the previous sections.

```
func sectionHeaderTapped(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag)

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {

        collapsed = CBool(arrayForBool[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section] as! NSNumber)
        print("Collapsed: ",collapsed)

        for i in 0 ..< sortedListAry.count {

            if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == i {
                arrayForBool[i] = !collapsed
                print("arrayForBool: ",arrayForBool)
                if (arrayForBool[i] as! Bool) == true{                       
                    let abc = (self.subListAry.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category_id") as! NSArray
                  if (abc.count == 0)
                    {
 //                        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//                            let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubCategory") as! subCat
//                            viewController.subCategoryID = ((self.sortedListAry.object(at:(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category_id") as? String)!

 //                           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: true)

                    }


                    else{

                        collapsed = true
                                categoryListTbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)
                        categoryListTbl.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

                    }
                }

               else{

                    collapsed = false
                    categoryListTbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain indexOfPreviouslyExpanded section. 
Assign -1 to it to start with. In your method check if there is some previously expanded section. You will need to reload  section of indexOfPreviouslyExpanded in addition to current expanded section. Also make sure to update indexOfPreviouslyExpanded every time you select a section.

Comment: Thank u Moh. sadiq for your valuable suggestion but i followed the exactly same what you said but it didn't collapse the previous section . I don't know what i am doing wrong could you elaborate more how i exactly do that

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
func sectionHeaderTapped(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 
gestureRecognizer.view!.tag)

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {

        collapsed = CBool(arrayForBool[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section] as! NSNumber)
        print("Collapsed: ",collapsed)

        for i in 0 ..< sortedListAry.count {

            if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == i {
                arrayForBool[i] = !collapsed
                print("arrayForBool: ",arrayForBool)
                if (arrayForBool[i] as! Bool) == true{
                    let abc = (self.subListAry.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category_id") as! NSArray
                    if (abc.count == 0)
                    {
                        //                        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        //                            let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubCategory") as! subCat
                        //                            viewController.subCategoryID = ((self.sortedListAry.object(at:(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category_id") as? String)!

                        //                           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController, animated: true)

                    }


                    else{

                        collapsed = true
                        categoryListTbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)
                        categoryListTbl.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

                    }
                }

                else{

                    collapsed = false
                    categoryListTbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)

                }
            }else {

                // here collapse all other section replace your bool array with value which you are using to collapse your section and reload tableview.

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a model of sectionData and add boolean variable to manage state of particular section

2.while creating add default value to true if you want to initially in collapse status.

3.In No of row method return 0 if section header state is true else no of row based on current section

```
     if self.graphDataArray?[section].collapsed == true {
            return 0
        }
```

4.Then on section button click use for in loop to check status of each section state and chnage current clicked section state to true
, rest state to false

5. reload data of tableview or call reloadsection.

   ```
   for i in 0..<self.graphDataArray!.count {
           let currentSectionModel = self.graphDataArray?[i]

           if i == section {

               currentSectionModel?.collapsed = false
               sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Minus"), for: .normal)
               sender.tintColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: hexBlueColor0036b9)
           }
           else{
               currentSectionModel?.collapsed = true
               sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Plus"), for: .normal)
               sender.tintColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: hexBlueColor0036b9)
           }

       }


       self.tblAnalysis.reloadData()
   ```

   //Happy coding